# Count images or "rel" attribute

Tags: jquery, image, count, each, rel

I´d like to count all images for one `<div class="thumbnail">` separately.

### My code:

```
    <div class="thumbnail">     

    <a rel="first" href="#">
        <div>
        <div></div>
        <img src="...">
        </div>
    </a>

    <div class="hidden-fb"> <!-- // CSS display: none -->                                                                                                 
        <a rel="first" href="#">
            <div>
            <div></div>
            <img src="...">
            </div>
        </a>                                               
    </div><!-- .hidden-fb -->

</div><!-- .thumbnail -->

<h2>Contains 2* images </h2>
```

### I try this

```
var featureImageCount = $('div.thumbnail img').length;    
$('div.thumbnail').after('<div><h1>' + featureImageCount + ' Images</h1></div>');
```

But I get just for all divs "(6)"
Can I do this with jquery, that the number* of images will be automatically fill out?
Or can jquery count the items by different `rel` attributes?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yCazz/7/)

Thanks
Ogni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('div.thumbnail').each(function () {

    var $this = $(this),
        count = $this.find('img').length;

    $this.after('<h2>', {
        text: 'Contains (' + count  + '*) image' + (count == 1 ? '' : 's')
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks - I done `$('.thumbnail').each(function () {

    var $this = $(this),
        count = $this.find('a').length;

        $this.after("<div><h1>" + count + " Images</h1></div>");
    });`

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at each `.thumbnail` element individually, using `.each`. Then, you can use `$(this)` in the callback to access the actual element. From there, you can find all specific descendent `<img>` elements. From there, you can just use `.after` like you attempt to, with `$(this)`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div.thumbnail").each(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            count = $this.children("a").children("img").length;
        $this.after("<div><h1>" + count + " Images</h1></div>");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yCazz/8/

Comment: Thanks. I updated your fiddle because I got just "1": [link]http://jsfiddle.net/yCazz/4/

Comment: @ogni You might've looked at a weird version of it. If you look at the fiddle I have in the answer now, it seems to work for me - shows "3", "2", "1"

Comment: Thanks. I updated my version, too because my code structur wasn´t right and some images are `display: none`, I use a fancybox gallery with just one linked preview image.